# Excel Cluster Bar(or Column) Chart

Tags: excel, events, charts

my data looks some thing like this:

```
Name    Event    Result
Bob     1       0
Mary    1       1
Sue     2       0
Tom     1       0
Dick    2       1
Harry   1       1
Mary    2       0
Sue     2       1
Dick    1       1
```

etc...

Names repeat, Event is the Event type, and Result is whether the event was successful or not (0, 1). What I want to end up with is a cluster bar chart with four bars to each name:

```
Event 1 # of Success
Event 1 # of Fail
Event 2 # of Success
Event 2 # of Fail
```

I figure I'll probably want to put this in a clustered stacked bar in the future, but if I can get the simple cluster going I can figure it out. A link to a good tutorial on event based charts would be appreciated. I'll keep searching and post back what I find. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure if this will fit your needs compleately, but it might be the quickest way to visualize the data:

Select your posted data, go to insert-tab, select pivot-chart (hides behind pivot-table) and insert it as a new sheet.

Then put the Event and the Result columns to the row-field and again the Event column to the value-field and set it up to use count instead of sum. Then you get the result beneath.

[image]

Comment: thanks that helps but not exactly what I was looking for. I will use that for other data visualization though.